# Upload feature from Google drive & local

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

Is there a way to upload a file from Google Drive to Blobstore using a Google Appengine Form.
In have a user form which require attachment feature . The attachment can be a file from local or from google Drive .

It Would be nice if any Google Developer post a Java reference code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Docs Picker to select a file on disk or on Google Drive : https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/?hl=fr

For Google Drive files, you can download its on App Engine and then store into the Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads
It's just reading file input stream and write file output stream where you want (but not on file system because it's impossible on App Engine for security reasons)

Relative to Google, there is no good reasons to use blobstore anymore so I advise you to use Cloud Storage.

Comment: +1, a note on the Blobstore and the whole file upload plumbering : with the App Engine file system restrictions, commons-fileupload is not usable. The BlobStore can still provide an "out of the box" mechanism to handle multipart files without hacking a streaming multipart file resolver.